# Revisions list Code Block stretches screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, revisions-list, diff

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

See the revision histories here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46344443/revisions
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/383658/revisions

The long code blocks page-stretch, as opposed to receiving their own max width and scrollbar (as they do on the Question page).

This caused me to misunderstand the "Side-by-Side" view's diff. It looked like an "answer" had been edited into the question, but there was no green text.

The right-hand side of the diff is completely off screen.

Comment: This is my doing.  I did work to make the diff elements work on responsive pages, but CSS seems to not consider the scrollable `<pre>` elements to be collapsable when they're sitting inside a `<table>`.  I'm gonna evaluate moving that page from being a massive table.

Comment: I noticed the same issue in this diff about a week ago: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/383658/revisions

Comment: @BrianNickel Making the diff view responsive with with limited width code blocks (i.e that have horizontal scrollbars) is possible with just CSS, without requiring any changes to the current HTML (i.e. using the existing HTML `<table>`). [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSHXl.gif)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is fixed.

When working on review queues, I switched from using fixed width tables to flexbox for rendering the side-by-side HTML diff, and apparently `<table>` elements are just as stubborn about `<pre>` element width as flexbox, if not more so.  Posts with wide enough code blocks caused the posts to explode outside of their containers.

Incidentally, we had a previously reported but similar problem with initial revisions (and possibly inline changes) for posts with very long code blocks, reported at [Revision page now fails the x-overflow](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/revision-page-now-fails-the-x-overflow).

I decided to go big here and just make the whole page responsive, replacing the table with carefully calculated header rows that collapse in a reasonable but Designed-by-a-Developer™ way.

Comment: There's also a [cross-site question mentioning the same problem on the 10k NATO tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402988/where-have-all-the-scrollbars-gone/) in addition to revisions

Comment: I have the feeling that the revision history page now has become extremely sluggish when scrolling, at least in Firefox (78.8.0esr (64-bit) - CPU usage goes to 100% for revisions with many diff lines). Seems fine in Chromium.