# Make display of reputation in revisions list consistent with the user card display

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, revisions-list, user-card

The user card in the revision list, for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/361476/revisions), shows the exact amount of reputation:

[image: screenshot of reputation displayed as 159011]

This is not consistent with how the flair works on (all?) other places in the site, e.g. under a post. There, the amount is displayed in units of thousands (k):

[image: screenshot of reputation displayed as 159k]

(or, in [very special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18874187/3), millions (m).)

It *used* to be consistent, see e.g. [this snapshot from 2017](http://web.archive.org/web/20170223105410/http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/119713/revisions):

[image: screenshot showing reputation displayed as 48.3k from a 2012 post]

Comment: This is definitely a recent bug. It used to be shown consistently.

Comment: @SebastianSimon you're right, I found an old example in the Wayback Machine.

Comment: Note: When you are less than 10K Flair you get [one place of decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIfgr.png).

Comment: Yes, this appears to be caused by a recent change. Another issue I noticed that could be related is that the vertical spacing has been reduced ([example](https://i.imgur.com/eGYqwtU.png)). The height of certain revision elements has also been reduced ([example](https://i.imgur.com/WSrwwIA.png)), although I don't think that that last one is an issue.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361474/348196) could be the recent change that caused all of that.

Comment: Now also reported on MSO: [User reputation is expanded in revision history page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405603/4642212).

Comment: Badges also show the incorrect glyph on sites that have custom badges, defaulting to the SE standard circle. [Raised in separate meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361516/179041)

Comment: Another side effect of this issue: suspended users normally have their badges hidden on user cards, and this used to also be in revision histories, but now they don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), screenshots for reference:

[image]

Comment: You're right. That change probably broke my [NSFW script](https://stackapps.com/a/8083/34061) as well.

Comment: I'm not sure any developer actually fixed this. The font change has been reverted which means the design codebase was reverted to some past version. Good chance it's a version before the bug that broke revisions, so when they'll fix it and apply the changes again, the bug reported here will come back. /cc @Glorfindel (maybe don't accept this just yet?)

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard I can always unaccept, and this change was unrelated to the font change (the bug is from February, the font change happened in May).

Comment: @Glorfindel I mean that perhaps something caused the codebase to revert to version even before February.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard After ["Segoe UI" font change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366367/312043), the reputation is displaying as expected.

Answer (score 10):

I prefer 151k instead of 151011, because to me it is more readable and I don't have to "count" the digits.

However I'd certainly be open also to supporting a modified feature request which asks to show 151.011k in your case, so that it's both easy to interpret and also exact/accurate.

Comment: Why 151.011k when just adding the comma (which would be consistent with other things around the site? The decimal plus k is *more* confusing than just "151,011".

Comment: @Catija The previous system with `k` just looked better.  It's especially irritating when trying to count the number of digits in the 1 million club.

Comment: "The decimal plus k is more confusing". Your rep currently says 87.1k. That's already how it is (with decimal plus k). Not sure how this could be "more" confusing.