# Site badge icons are not used on new revisions screen

Tags: bug, design, badges, revisions-list

With the latest change to the revisions screen, a site's custom badges are not displayed on the user card. Here's an example - you can see the custom badges used for Arqade on the top bar, while the revision entry uses the SE default circle instead:

[image: Badges]

Comment: Probably related to [Make display of reputation in revisions list consistent with the rest of the flairs again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361478/289905); maybe the same cause.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - yep, I [commented on that meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361478/make-display-of-reputation-in-revisions-list-consistent-with-the-rest-of-the-fla#comment1206166_361478), but thought it best if this was a separate report, as that meta focuses mainly on the display of rep points