# Badge/reputation-rich editor's achievements poke through the sidebar in timeline

Tags: bug, design, timeline

A minute or so ago Shog [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/363838/20) a post, and his considerable bronze badge count shoved through the side of the gray bar:

[image]

Same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67373825/2), where Jon's hefty reputation sum exacerbated the problem:

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Make display of reputation in revisions list consistent with the user card display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361478/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel OK maybe, once that bug is fixed this one will be too...

Comment: That's what I mean, yes.

Comment: This might differ a bit between resolutions. The Jon Skeet overflow is more pronounced on your screen [than on mine](https://i.imgur.com/Pd8BJd6.png).

Comment: Could be. I'm on FF 88 x64, 2k monitor. You?

Comment: @Glorfindel I decided it was similar enough - the answers would be - and closed it as a duplicate.