# Scrollbars are still broken on the 10k new answers to old questions tool

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools, scrolling, horizontal-scroll-bar

Scrollbars on the [10k NATO (New Answers To Old) tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) are still broken if there's a code block on the page requiring large amounts of horizontal space, forcing the page to become substantially wider than it should be. I believe this is identical in terms of the cause to the problem occurring on the revisions page, but the patch to the revisions page didn't fix the problem for the 10k tool.

With [my original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402988/6296561) on MSO marked [status-complete] (and the same for [the partial equivalent here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361318/332043), which only addresses the problem with revisions), [and my comment being ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361318/revisions-list-code-block-stretches-screen/361474#comment1206386_361474) for almost two months, I'm reopening a part of this problem as a new post.

> [image: Image showing the 10k NATO tool content overflowing due to the lack of a code scrollbar]

Or, even worse (reproduced on 28.04.2021 in FF 88.0 and Chromium, the latter of which has no userscripts or plugins active):

> [image: Image showing the 10k NATO tool content overflowing substantially worse due to a very long code block]

You could fit that horizontally on 6-8 Full HD screens, for the record. <sub><sub>well, 7.93 ≈ 8, but that doesn't sound as fun :p</sub></sub>

Comment: I can confirm that at this point in time it is utterly broken, but no large horizontal code block is visible this time, at least here at MSE.

Comment: @Catija it's commonly referred to as NATO around SOCVR and SOBotics. Not complaining about the edit (it being used there doesn't mean the entire network knows about it, even if I initially assumed it was a common abbreviation), just a bit of useless information for the record

Comment: It seems pretty inconsistent. Sometimes it's fine, sometimes it's a bit off. But I just got one 29686 pixels on my screen,... and the `#mainbar` element containing it is 732 pixels wide for me :|